# Set specific values on x axis on a logarithmic plot

Tags: pgfplots, plot, csv, ticks

I made the following plot

[image]

And it comes from data that I stored on a `.csv`, now the x axis is on a logarithmic scale and I only want ticks right below the points that are plotted. Fortunately, all of these are powers of 2, and the go from 2^3, 2^6, 2^9,... to 2^27 in steps of 3 each power. How can I do this?

Here's the code that makes the plot.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmode=log, log base x = 2, xticks, xlabel={\(\lg(n)\)}, ylabel={\(t \left[ \mathrm{ns} \right]\)}]
\addplot table [x=n, y=t_mean, col sep=comma] {time_data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s solved by the TO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it! All I needed to do was add the option `xtick=data`!

Comment: If you wait aa day or so, you can accept your own answer.